# Theory behind wheeled inverted pendulum robots

Tags: control, wheeled-robot, dynamics, theory, balance

I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of the theory behind wheeled self-balancing robots. Can anyone point me to a text on dynamic modelling and control theory that might help?

Comment: I haven't got a high enough rep atm to ask in robotics chat.

Comment: You need [20 points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158873/337600) across all sites to get into chat. It looks like you have a network profile under the name "stevesy" that *should* be enough to get in, but your profile here "5_5" only had 10 points. I'm not sure how that works, but I upvoted here and [your other question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/12447/9720) to get you the 20 points you need to get into chat :)